# Supabase Auth - redirectTo not working for OAuth

Tags: ios, react-native, redirect, supabase

I am switching from Flutter to Supabase and am running into an issue with Authentication. Although I can successfully launch the URL with the correct redirect value, I keep getting redirected to the site URL which should only be used for web, not iOS or Android. Below is the function I am using for Apple but this is happening with all other providers as well.

```
const isWeb = Platform.OS === "web";
const redirectTo = isWeb
  ? "https://web.example.com/login-callback/"
  : "com.example.react://login-callback/";

export const signInWithApple = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: "apple",
    options: {
      redirectTo: redirectTo,
    },
  });

  if (error !== null) {
    console.log(error?.message);
    return "error";
  } else {
    console.log(data);
    Linking.openURL(data.url);
    return "success";
  }
};
```

The URL that gets logged before launching is correct, for example,  `LOG  {"provider": "apple", "url": "https://api.example.com/auth/v1/authorize?provider=apple&redirect_to=com.example.react%3A%2F%2Flogin-callback%2F"}`, but I always get redirected to something like `https://web.example.com/#access_token=*****`. I had a similar issue with Flutter, and that was because I had not added the additional redirect in Supabase but I already did that. I also confirmed that I have `CFBundleURLSchemes` set in the `info.plist` for iOS but that did not fix it.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the configuration of the additional redirect URL in your Supabase dashboard. You have to paste precisely the same value as what you pass to `redirectTo` there. You cannot have extra `/` or anything or otherwise it won't work. Double check that you have exactly `com.example.react://login-callback/` set as a value in your additional redirect URL.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this is not the issue. I have exactly the same thing in additional redirect URL as I use for `redirectTo`. I configured it the same way as I had working in Flutter.

Comment: Hmm, if you are absolutely sure that the redirectTo value matches the value in Additional redirect URLs, then it might be best to contact support https://app.supabase.com/support/new

Comment: Since I am self-hosting Supabase I don't think their support will help. I will open an issue on GitHub, though.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. This issue was related to self-hosting. Instead of having `ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS="URL,URL,URL"` I had `ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS="URL, URL, URL"` which apparently made a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF SELF-HOSTING:

Check that you do not have spaces after commas in `ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS`.

Correct ✅ :
`ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS="URL,URL,URL"`

Incorrect ❌ :
`ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS="URL, URL, URL"`

Comment: Stumbled across this post trying to solve the same issue, but I'm not self-hosting... If anyone is NOT self-hosting, i.e. using Supabase's free or paid plans, the site url and redirect urls need to be setup in the dashboard under Dashboard > Authentication > URL Configuration